# How to solve The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request when ContentLength increases

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Whenever i try to send notification to more then 20 users it gives an error The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. I have tried all the solution but it gives same error.
Here is my code:-

```
private string SendGCMNotification(string apiKey, string postData)
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest wRequest;
            wRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            wRequest.Method = "POST";
            wRequest.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
            wRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", apiKey));

            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            wRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            var stream = wRequest.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream.Close();

            var wResponse = wRequest.GetResponse();
            stream = wResponse.GetResponseStream();
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var response = reader.ReadToEnd();

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wResponse;
            var status = httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString();

            reader.Close();
            stream.Close();
            wResponse.Close();

            //TODO check status
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        return "sent";
    }
```

My web.config file :-

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="30000000" maxUrl="10000" maxQueryString="10000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

  </system.webServer>

  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: Which one does return 400? The google server? Then there is nothing you can do in your web.config (because that's the configuration for YOUR server) but you have to consult google docs on the format and restrictions with the requests to their api. Maybe it's not allowed to include more then 20 devices in one call?

Comment: i have studied the google [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json),it shows that at one time we can include 1000 devices and i'm getting this error at  GetResponse()

Comment: Well, something is wrong with your postdata or request. Otherwise there wouldn't be a 400.

Comment: @derpirscher thank you there is problem in my postdata,i have checked all the ids and in one of my registration id there was some link due to which its giving 404..

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this as solved. To do so, please add an answer below, and self-accept (tick) it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my postdata.`<div>` tag gets inserted into my db with endpoint.

Here is code that causes problem

```
{ "registration_ids": [ "e-9zZTY0LtI:APA91bFTZUYD4kghBu1xU4cO3A9aqzCN_QqX7fZECoQlcGC-PvDg5_fOPMZgNHTBZqk-4jwk6iAfWjJlD6BUu4iGmnXHqjpo-40FR6f4kgjnHGS6TBGOR2Vii7CqxPhvr7OE1RyX8JHy <div style="display:none">viagra.com coupon</div>" ], "data": {"contentTitle":"content title GCM", "message": "some test message"}}
```

By removing this from registration id solved my problem

```
<div style="display:none">viagra.com coupon</div>
```